# How to migrate from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

As `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is `@Deprecated`, how can I correctly move to `org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain`?

I mean, what is the equivalent of the following deprecated configuration?

```
@Configuration
static class HttpSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: That has been documented [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) (and also in the documentation of Spring Security 5.4.x which was the first to add this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) remove the `extends` and expose the `SecurityFilterChain`.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
static class HttpSecurityConfiguration {
    @public
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Ideally you would rewrite the authorize part as well.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
static class HttpSecurityConfiguration {
    @public
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests( (auth) -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage using lambda expression in `authorizeHttpRequests()`?

Comment: Better organization and formatting of your code. With the lambda you are gonna have just 1 level of indentation, making it easier to read the code. Without it, you have to chain the method calls and use `and()`, making it hard to format the code.

Comment: You're right except in M. Deinum example this does not appear since http is used on every line. I edit the answer.

Comment: You can use it on each line or chain it. That doesn't matter both will work equally well and is a matter of taste.